# Script that exports enviromental variables cannot export them

Tags: bash, shell-script, environment-variables

I have the following script named `export.sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

SOURCE="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
while [ -h "$SOURCE" ]; do # resolve $SOURCE until the file is no longer a symlink
  DIR="$( cd -P "$( dirname "$SOURCE" )" && pwd )"
  SOURCE="$(readlink "$SOURCE")"
  [[ $SOURCE != /* ]] && SOURCE="$DIR/$SOURCE" # if $SOURCE was a relative symlink, we need to resolve it relative to the path where the symlink file was located
done

SOURCE=$(dirname ${SOURCE})

export $(cat "${SOURCE}/../params.env" | xargs)
```

In some words what it does it to export enviromental variables from a file named `params.env` that is located by convention on the prarent folder and exports the contents as enviromental variables.

Sample contents of `params.env` file are:

```
SOMEVAR="val1"
SOMEVAR2="val2"
```

And a successfull run will provide me `SOMEVAR` with value `val1` and `SOMEVAR2` with value `val2` enviromental variables.

But if I run:

```
./export.sh
```

And afterwards

```
printenv | grep SOMEVAR
```

It does not show that the enviromental variable is set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire idea is right, but you you end up *executing* the shell script rather than *sourcing* it to make the environment changes in the current shell.

Remember always, executing a script runs a sub-shell and all the exported system environment variables are *lost* after the sub-shell is terminated.

See what happens when you run the script is executed, with the debug mode set `-x` (FYI, am using `params.env` from the current folder)

```
$ bash -x script.sh
+ SOURCE=script.sh
+ '[' -h script.sh ']'
++ dirname script.sh
+ SOURCE=.
++ cat ./params.env
++ xargs
+ export SOMEVAR=val1 SOMEVAR2=val2
+ SOMEVAR=val1
+ SOMEVAR2=val2
```

You can see the variables are set but the sub-shell destroys the variables exported. Now on sourcing the script,

```
source script.sh
printenv | grep SOMEVAR
SOMEVAR=val1
SOMEVAR2=val2
```

If your `bash` version does not support an explicit `source` command, use the `POSIX` compliant ways of doing `. ./script.sh`